# Create a string "Build" number for procedures and module

Tags: vba, excel, classes

The class assigns various strings to the build number. So the build might look like `3.4.5.1` which would be of the format `version.major.minor.patch`. When picking *set codever* button, it assigns (or replaces) the current `MsCodeVer` with the new string. so basically, I have a global `var MsCodeVer` that is used in every procedure in the workbook (if so desired) to help in tracking when I update a proc or module. I have other addins that use these global vars that can update libraries automatically. So, for me, this is helpful in tracking the development of code.

This is just my second class (but really the first class I have written). I would like to know if I got the 'class' part right?

To see it in action (with the user forms and modules), is there a place that I can upload the entire workbook to for further testing?

Below is `CCodeVer` class

```
    '@IgnoreModule ArgumentWithIncompatibleObjectType, UnassignedVariableUsage, VariableNotAssigned, ConstantNotUsed, ProcedureNotUsed
    Option Explicit
    Private m_Patch As String
    Private m_Minor As String
    Private m_Major As String
    Private m_Version As String
    Private m_CodeVer As String
    Private Const MSCODEVERMOD As String = "3.0.4"
    '@Folder("Commands")

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()

        MsCodeVer = "3.0.4.1"

        m_Patch = "0"
        m_Minor = "0"
        m_Major = "0"
        m_Version = "0"
        m_CodeVer = m_Version & SEP & m_Major & SEP & m_Minor & SEP & m_Patch
        
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate()

        MsCodeVer = "3.0.4.1"

        'do i really need to do anything here?
        
    End Sub

    Public Property Get CodeVerS() As String: Version = m_CodeVer: End Property

    Public Property Let CodeVerS(ByVal CV As String): m_Version = CV: End Property

    Public Property Get Major() As String: Major = m_Major: End Property

    Public Property Let Major(ByVal Maj As String): m_Major = Maj: End Property

    Public Property Get Minor() As String: Minor = m_Minor: End Property

    Public Property Let Minor(ByVal Min As String): m_Minor = Min: End Property

    Public Property Get Patch() As String: Patch = m_Patch: End Property

    Public Property Let Patch(ByVal Pat As String): m_Patch = Pat: End Property

    Public Property Get Version() As String: Version = m_Version: End Property

    Public Property Let Version(ByVal Ver As String): m_Version = Ver: End Property

    Public Sub AddCodeVer(ByVal Workbook As String, ByVal Module As String, ByVal Procedure As String, ByVal CodeVerString As String)

        MsCodeVer = "3.0.4.1"

        Dim VbProj   As VBIDE.VBProject
        Dim VbComp   As VBIDE.VBComponent
        Dim CodeMod  As VBIDE.CodeModule
        Dim LineNum    As Long
        Dim ProcKind   As VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind
        Dim StartLine As Long
        Dim EndLine As Long
        Dim CountOfLine As Long
        Dim Ai As AddIn
        Dim Wb As Workbook
        Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult
        
        If CodeVerString = SNOVC Then Exit Sub

        On Error GoTo errHandler
        
        'check for empty workbook combobox which means
        'all open, unprotected workbooks and addins
        If MobjUserForm.cbo_Workbook.Value = vbNullString Then
            Answer = MsgBox("This will add the MsCodeVer string to all open" & vbCr & _
                "and unprotected workbooks. This could take some time. Ok to continue? ", _
                vbYesNo, "Process Workbooks?")
            If Answer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
            For Each Wb In Workbooks
                If Not Wb.ProtectWindows Or _
                    Not Wb.ProtectStructure Or _
                    Not Wb.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Then
                    Workbook = Wb.Name
                    Set VbProj = Wb.VBProject
                    For Each VbComp In VbProj.VBComponents
                        Module = VbComp.Name
                        Set CodeMod = VbComp.CodeModule
                        With CodeMod
                            LineNum = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1
                            Do Until LineNum >= .CountOfLines
                                Procedure = .ProcOfLine(LineNum, ProcKind)
                                Select Case ProcKind
                                    Case vbext_pk_Get
                                        Procedure = Procedure & "  (Get)"
                                    Case vbext_pk_Let
                                        Procedure = Procedure & "  (Let)"
                                    Case vbext_pk_Set
                                        Procedure = Procedure & "  (Set)"
                                End Select
                                If ProcKind = vbext_pk_Proc Then
                                    StartLine = .ProcBodyLine(Procedure, vbext_pk_Proc)
                                    EndLine = StartLine - 2 + .ProcCountLines(Procedure, vbext_pk_Proc)
                                    Call SearchModule(Workbook, Module, Procedure, CodeVerString, CodeMod, StartLine, EndLine)
                                End If
                                LineNum = .ProcStartLine(Split(Procedure, "  (")(0), ProcKind) + _
                                    .ProcCountLines(Split(Procedure, "  (")(0), ProcKind) + 1
                            Loop
                        End With
                    Next VbComp
                End If
            Next Wb
            Answer = MsgBox("This will add the MsCodeVer string to all open" & vbCr & _
                "installed and unprotected addins. This could take some time. Ok to continue? ", _
                vbYesNo, "Process AddIns?")
            If Answer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
            For Each Ai In Application.VBE.AddIns
                If Not Ai.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Or _
                    Not Right(Ai.Name, 3) = "XLL" Or _
                    Ai.Installed Or _
                    Not IsProtectedAi(Ai) Then
                    Workbook = Ai.Name
                    Set VbProj = Workbooks(Ai.Name).VBProject
                    For Each VbComp In VbProj.VBComponents
                        Module = VbComp.Name
                        Set CodeMod = VbComp.CodeModule
                        With CodeMod
                            LineNum = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1
                            Do Until LineNum >= .CountOfLines
                                Procedure = .ProcOfLine(LineNum, ProcKind)
                                Select Case ProcKind
                                    Case vbext_pk_Get
                                        Procedure = Procedure & "  (Get)"
                                    Case vbext_pk_Let
                                        Procedure = Procedure & "  (Let)"
                                    Case vbext_pk_Set
                                        Procedure = Procedure & "  (Set)"
                                End Select
                                If ProcKind = vbext_pk_Proc Then
                                    StartLine = .ProcBodyLine(Procedure, vbext_pk_Proc)
                                    EndLine = StartLine - 2 + .ProcCountLines(Procedure, vbext_pk_Proc)
                                    Call SearchModule(Workbook, Module, Procedure, CodeVerString, CodeMod, StartLine, EndLine)
                                End If
                                LineNum = .ProcStartLine(Split(Procedure, "  (")(0), ProcKind) + _
                                    .ProcCountLines(Split(Procedure, "  (")(0), ProcKind) + 1
                            Loop
                        End With
                    Next VbComp
                End If
            Next Ai
            'check for empty module combobox
            'which means all modules in selected workbook
        ElseIf MobjUserForm.cbo_Module.Value = vbNullString Then
            Workbook = MobjUserForm.cbo_Workbook.Value
            Set VbProj = Workbooks(MobjUserForm.cbo_Workbook.Value).VBProject
            For Each VbComp In VbProj.VBComponents
                Module = VbComp.Name
                Set CodeMod = VbComp.CodeModule
                With CodeMod
                    LineNum = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1
                    Do Until LineNum >= .CountOfLines
                        Procedure = .ProcOfLine(LineNum, ProcKind)
                        Select Case ProcKind
                            Case vbext_pk_Get
                                Procedure = Procedure & "  (Get)"
                            Case vbext_pk_Let
                                Procedure = Procedure & "  (Let)"
                            Case vbext_pk_Set
                                Procedure = Procedure & "  (Set)"
                        End Select
                        If ProcKind = vbext_pk_Proc Then
                            StartLine = .ProcBodyLine(Procedure, vbext_pk_Proc)
                            EndLine = StartLine - 2 + .ProcCountLines(Procedure, vbext_pk_Proc)
                            Call SearchModule(Workbook, Module, Procedure, CodeVerString, CodeMod, StartLine, EndLine)
                        End If
                        LineNum = .ProcStartLine(Split(Procedure, "  (")(0), ProcKind) + _
                            .ProcCountLines(Split(Procedure, "  (")(0), ProcKind) + 1
                    Loop
                End With
            Next VbComp
            'check for empty procedure combobox
            'which means all procedures in the selected module
        ElseIf MobjUserForm.cbo_Procedure.Value = vbNullString Then
            Workbook = MobjUserForm.cbo_Workbook.Value
            Module = MobjUserForm.cbo_Module.Value
            Set CodeMod = Workbooks(Workbook).VBProject.VBComponents(Module).CodeModule
            With CodeMod
                LineNum = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1
                Do Until LineNum >= .CountOfLines
                    Procedure = .ProcOfLine(LineNum, ProcKind)
                    Select Case ProcKind
                        Case vbext_pk_Get
                            Procedure = Procedure & "  (Get)"
                        Case vbext_pk_Let
                            Procedure = Procedure & "  (Let)"
                        Case vbext_pk_Set
                            Procedure = Procedure & "  (Set)"
                    End Select
                    If ProcKind = vbext_pk_Proc Then
                        StartLine = .ProcBodyLine(Procedure, vbext_pk_Proc)
                        EndLine = StartLine - 2 + .ProcCountLines(Procedure, vbext_pk_Proc)
                        Call SearchModule(Workbook, Module, Procedure, CodeVerString, CodeMod, StartLine, EndLine)
                    End If
                    LineNum = .ProcStartLine(Split(Procedure, "  (")(0), ProcKind) + _
                        .ProcCountLines(Split(Procedure, "  (")(0), ProcKind) + 1
                Loop
            End With
        Else
            Set CodeMod = Workbooks(Workbook).VBProject.VBComponents(Module).CodeModule
            With CodeMod
                StartLine = .ProcBodyLine(Procedure, vbext_pk_Proc)
                EndLine = StartLine - 2 + .ProcCountLines(Procedure, vbext_pk_Proc)
                Call SearchModule(Workbook, Module, Procedure, CodeVerString, CodeMod, StartLine, EndLine)
            End With
        End If
            
        Exit Sub
        
    errHandler:
        
        MsgBox ("CCodeVer " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description)
        Stop
        Resume
        
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddCodeVerVar(ByVal Workbook As String, Optional bDelete As Boolean = False)
        
        Dim VbComp As VBComponent
        Dim Counter As Long
        Dim TrimLines As String
        Dim Found As Boolean
        
        For Each VbComp In Workbooks(Workbook).VBProject.VBComponents
            With VbComp.CodeModule
                For Counter = 1 To .CountOfDeclarationLines
                    TrimLines = Trim(.Lines(Counter, 1))
                    If TrimLines Like "Public MsCodeVer as String*" Then
                        Found = True
                        If bDelete Then VbComp.CodeModule.DeleteLines (Counter)
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                Next Counter
                If Not Found Then
                    If Not ModExists(Workbook, "MDeclare") Then
                        Set VbComp = Workbooks(Workbook).VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
                        With VbComp
                            .Name = "MDeclare"
                            .CodeModule.InsertLines (.CodeModule.CountOfDeclarationLines + 1), "Public MsCodeVer as String"
                        End With
                    End If
                    Exit For
                Else
                    Set VbComp = Workbooks(Workbook).VBProject.VBComponents("MDeclare")
                    VbComp.CodeModule.InsertLines (VbComp.CodeModule.CountOfDeclarationLines + 1), "Public MsCodeVer as String"
                End If
            End With
        Next VbComp
        
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddCodeVerVersionConst(ByVal Workbook As String, ByVal Version As String, Optional bDelete As Boolean = False)
        
        Dim VbComp As VBComponent
        Dim Counter As Long
        Dim TrimLines As String
        Dim Found As Boolean
        
        For Each VbComp In Workbooks(Workbook).VBProject.VBComponents
            If VbComp.Name = "MDeclare" Then
            With VbComp.CodeModule
                For Counter = 1 To .CountOfDeclarationLines
                    TrimLines = Trim(.Lines(Counter, 1))
                    If TrimLines Like "Public Const MSVERSION As String = *" Then
                        Found = True
                        If bDelete Then
                            VbComp.CodeModule.DeleteLines Counter
                        Else
                            VbComp.CodeModule.ReplaceLine Counter, "Public Const MSVERSION As String = " & Chr(34) & Version & Chr(34)
                        End If
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                Next Counter
            End With
            End If
        Next VbComp

        If Not Found Then
            If Not ModExists(Workbook, "MDeclare") Then
                Set VbComp = Workbooks(Workbook).VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
                With VbComp
                    .Name = "MDeclare"
                    .CodeModule.InsertLines (.CodeModule.CountOfDeclarationLines + 1), "Public Const MSVERSION As String = " & Chr(34) & Version & Chr(34)
                End With
            End If
        Else
            Set VbComp = Workbooks(Workbook).VBProject.VBComponents("MDeclare")
            VbComp.CodeModule.InsertLines (VbComp.CodeModule.CountOfDeclarationLines + 1), "Public Const MSVERSION As String = " & Chr(34) & Version & Chr(34)
        End If

    End Sub

    Public Function AddMajor(Major As Long) As String
     
        MsCodeVer = "3.0.4.1"

        Dim CvSplit As Variant
        
        CvSplit = Split(MobjUserForm.txt_VersionControlString.Value, ".")
        
        m_Version = CvSplit(0)
        m_Major = CvSplit(1)
        m_Minor = CvSplit(2)
        m_Patch = CvSplit(3)
        
        AddMajor = Format(CLng(m_Major) + Major, "0")
        
        If MobjUserForm.chk_ShowLeadingZeros.Value = True Then
            AddMajor = Format(CLng(m_Major) + Major, "0000")
        Else
            AddMajor = Format(CLng(m_Major) + Major, "0")
        End If
        
        If AddMajor > 9999 Then
            AddMajor = "0"
            m_Major = "0"
            m_Version = CStr(CLng(m_Version + 1))
        End If
        If CLng(m_Version) >= 999999 Then
            MsgBox ("Resetting to base string")
            m_Version = "0"
            m_Major = "0"
            m_Minor = "0"
            m_Patch = "0"
        End If
        
        m_CodeVer = m_Version & SEP & AddMajor & SEP & m_Minor & SEP & m_Patch
        
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        MobjUserForm.txt_VersionControlString = m_CodeVer
        Application.EnableEvents = True
            
    End Function

    Public Function AddMinor(Minor As Long) As String

        MsCodeVer = "3.0.4.1"

        Dim CvSplit As Variant
        
        CvSplit = Split(MobjUserForm.txt_VersionControlString.Value, ".")
        
        m_Version = CvSplit(0)
        m_Major = CvSplit(1)
        m_Minor = CvSplit(2)
        m_Patch = CvSplit(3)
        
        AddMinor = Format(CLng(m_Minor) + Minor, "0")
        
        If MobjUserForm.chk_ShowLeadingZeros.Value = True Then
            AddMinor = Format(CLng(m_Minor) + Minor, "0000")
        Else
            AddMinor = Format(CLng(m_Minor) + Minor, "0")
        End If
        
        If AddMinor > 9999 Then
            AddMinor = "0"
            m_Minor = "0"
            m_Major = CStr(CLng(m_Major + 1))
        End If
        If CLng(m_Major) > 9999 Then
            m_Major = "0"
            m_Version = CStr(CLng(m_Version + 1))
        End If
        If CLng(m_Version) >= 999999 Then
            MsgBox ("Resetting to base string")
            m_Version = "0"
            If CvSplit(1) = "9999" Then m_Major = "0"
            If CvSplit(2) = "9999" Then m_Minor = "0"
            If CvSplit(3) = "9999" Then m_Patch = "0"
        End If
        
        m_CodeVer = m_Version & SEP & m_Major & SEP & AddMinor & SEP & m_Patch
        
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        MobjUserForm.txt_VersionControlString = m_CodeVer
        Application.EnableEvents = True
            
    End Function

    Public Function AddPatch(Patch As Long) As String

        MsCodeVer = "3.0.4.1"

        Dim CvSplit As Variant
        
        CvSplit = Split(MobjUserForm.txt_VersionControlString.Value, ".")
        
        m_Version = CvSplit(0)
        m_Major = CvSplit(1)
        m_Minor = CvSplit(2)
        m_Patch = CvSplit(3)
        
        AddPatch = Format(CLng(m_Patch) + Patch, "0")
        
        If MobjUserForm.chk_ShowLeadingZeros.Value = True Then
            AddPatch = Format(CLng(m_Patch) + Patch, "0000")
        Else
            AddPatch = Format(CLng(m_Patch) + Patch, "0")
        End If

        If AddPatch > 9999 Then
            AddPatch = 0
            m_Patch = "0"
            m_Minor = CStr(CLng(m_Minor + 1))
        End If
        If CLng(m_Minor) > 9999 Then
            m_Minor = "0"
            m_Major = CStr(CLng(m_Major + 1))
        End If
        If CLng(m_Major) > 9999 Then
            m_Major = "0"
            m_Version = CStr(CLng(m_Version + 1))
        End If
        If CLng(m_Version) >= 999999 Then
            MsgBox ("Resetting to base string")
            m_Version = "0"
            If CvSplit(1) = "9999" Then m_Major = "0"
            If CvSplit(2) = "9999" Then m_Minor = "0"
            If CvSplit(3) = "9999" Then m_Patch = "0"
        End If

        m_CodeVer = m_Version & SEP & m_Major & SEP & m_Minor & SEP & AddPatch
        
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        MobjUserForm.txt_VersionControlString = m_CodeVer
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        
    End Function

    Public Function AddVersion(Version As Long) As String

        MsCodeVer = "3.0.4.1"

        Dim CvSplit As Variant
        
        CvSplit = Split(MobjUserForm.txt_VersionControlString.Value, ".")
        
        AddVersion = Format(CLng(CvSplit(0)) + Version, "0")
        
        m_Version = AddVersion
        m_Major = CvSplit(1)
        m_Minor = CvSplit(2)
        m_Patch = CvSplit(3)
        
        If AddVersion > 999999 Then
            AddVersion = "0"
            MsgBox ("Resetting to base string")
            m_Version = "0"
            If CvSplit(1) = "9999" Then m_Major = "0"
            If CvSplit(2) = "9999" Then m_Minor = "0"
            If CvSplit(3) = "9999" Then m_Patch = "0"
        End If
        
        If MobjUserForm.chk_UpdateVersion.Value = True Then
            Call AddCodeVerVersionConst(MobjUserForm.cbo_Workbook.Value, AddVersion)
            MobjUserForm.chk_UpdateVersion.Value = False
        End If
            
        m_CodeVer = AddVersion & SEP & m_Major & SEP & m_Minor & SEP & m_Patch
        
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        MobjUserForm.txt_VersionControlString = m_CodeVer
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        
    End Function

    Function FindLastParenthesis(ByVal Workbook As String, ByVal Module As String, ByVal Procedure As String) As Long

        MsCodeVer = "3.0.4.1"

        Dim CountOfLines As Long
        Dim EndLine As Long
        Dim StartLine As Long
        Dim TrimLines As String
        Dim CodMod As CodeModule
        Dim LeftCount As Long
        Dim RightCount As Long
        Dim InnerCount As Long
        
        Set CodMod = Workbooks(Workbook).VBProject.VBComponents(Module).CodeModule

        StartLine = GetProcInfo(Workbook, Module, Procedure, "StartLine")
        EndLine = GetProcInfo(Workbook, Module, Procedure, "EndLine")
        
        With CodMod
            For CountOfLines = StartLine To EndLine - 1
                TrimLines = Trim(.Lines(CountOfLines, 1))
                LeftCount = Len(TrimLines) - Len(Replace(TrimLines, "(", vbNullString))
                    RightCount = Len(TrimLines) - Len(Replace(TrimLines, ")", vbNullString))
                    If LeftCount = RightCount Then
                        FindLastParenthesis = CountOfLines
                        Exit Function
                    End If
                    If Right(TrimLines, 1) = ")" Then 'Or sTrimLines Like "*)*" Then
                        FindLastParenthesis = CountOfLines
                        Exit Function
                    End If
                    For InnerCount = CountOfLines To .CountOfLines 'skip to next line and look for ')'
                        TrimLines = Trim(.Lines(InnerCount, 1))
                        If TrimLines Like "*)*" Then
                            FindLastParenthesis = InnerCount 'either this is plus one, or the above is wrong (no plus one)
                            Exit Function
                        End If
                    Next InnerCount
            Next CountOfLines
        End With

    End Function

    Function GetProcCount(Workbook As String, Module As String) As Long

        Dim CodeMod  As VBIDE.CodeModule
        Dim CodeVer As CCodeVer
        Dim LineNum As Long
        Dim ProcKind As VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind
        Dim ProcName As String
        Dim ProcCount As Long
        
        Set CodeVer = New CCodeVer
        Set CodeMod = Workbooks(Workbook).VBProject.VBComponents(Module).CodeModule
        
        With CodeMod
            LineNum = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1
            Do Until LineNum >= .CountOfLines
                ProcName = .ProcOfLine(LineNum, ProcKind)
                If ProcKind = vbext_pk_Proc Then
                    ProcCount = ProcCount + 1
                End If
                LineNum = .ProcStartLine(Split(ProcName, "  (")(0), ProcKind) + _
                    .ProcCountLines(Split(ProcName, "  (")(0), ProcKind) + 1
            Loop
        End With
        
        GetProcCount = ProcCount
        
    End Function

    Function GetProcInfo(Workbook As String, Module As String, Procedure As String, sCommand As String) As Variant

        MsCodeVer = "3.0.4.1"

        Dim BodyCount As Long
        Dim EndProc As Long
        Dim Header As Long
        Dim ProcSize As Long
        Dim ProcStart As Long
        Dim StartLine As Long
        Dim ProcType As String
        Dim MyString As String
        Dim CodMod As CodeModule
        
        Set CodMod = Workbooks(Workbook).VBProject.VBComponents(Module).CodeModule

        With CodMod
            StartLine = .ProcBodyLine(Procedure, vbext_pk_Proc)
            ProcSize = .ProcCountLines(Procedure, vbext_pk_Proc) - .ProcBodyLine(Procedure, vbext_pk_Proc) + .ProcStartLine(Procedure, vbext_pk_Proc)
            Procedure = .ProcOfLine(StartLine, vbext_pk_Proc)
            ProcStart = .ProcStartLine(Procedure, vbext_pk_Proc)
            BodyCount = ProcSize - 2
            EndProc = StartLine + ProcSize - 1
            Header = StartLine - ProcStart
            ProcType = Split(.Lines(StartLine, 1), " " & Procedure)(0)
            MyString = MyString & "The procedure definition starts on line " & StartLine & vbCr
            MyString = MyString & "The total size of procedure inc definition and end command is " & ProcSize & vbCr
            MyString = MyString & "The procedure name is " & Procedure & vbCr
            MyString = MyString & "The start of the header or blank line is " & ProcStart & vbCr
            MyString = MyString & "The body line count is " & BodyCount & vbCr
            MyString = MyString & "The procedure ends on line " & EndProc & vbCr
            MyString = MyString & "The header and blank line count is " & Header & vbCr
            MyString = MyString & "The type of procedure is a " & ProcType
            'Debug.Print sString
        End With

        If sCommand = "StartLine" Then
            GetProcInfo = StartLine
        ElseIf sCommand = "EndLine" Then
            GetProcInfo = EndProc
        ElseIf sCommand = "BodyLength" Then
            GetProcInfo = BodyCount
        ElseIf sCommand = "ProcName" Then
            GetProcInfo = Procedure
        ElseIf sCommand = "ProcTotal" Then
            GetProcInfo = ProcSize
        ElseIf sCommand = "ProcType" Then
            GetProcInfo = ProcType
        ElseIf sCommand = "HeaderInfo" Then
            GetProcInfo = Header
        ElseIf sCommand = "HeaderStart" Then
            GetProcInfo = ProcStart
        ElseIf sCommand = "FullList" Then
            MsgBox MyString
        Else
            MsgBox ("Your Command argument is invalid. Only values that are acceptable are" & vbCr & _
                "StartLine, EndLine, BodyLength, ProcName, ProcTotal, ProcType, HeaderInfo, HeaderStart or FullList")
        End If

    End Function

    Public Function MinusMajor(Major As Long) As String

        MsCodeVer = "3.0.4.1"

        Dim CvSplit As Variant
        
        CvSplit = Split(MobjUserForm.txt_VersionControlString.Value, ".")
        
        MinusMajor = Format(CLng(CvSplit(1)) - Major, "0")

        If MobjUserForm.chk_ShowLeadingZeros.Value = True Then
            MinusMajor = Format(CLng(CvSplit(1)) - Major, "0000")
            If MinusMajor < 0 Then MinusMajor = "0000"
        Else
            MinusMajor = Format(CLng(CvSplit(1)) - Major, "0")
            If MinusMajor < 0 Then MinusMajor = "0"
        End If

        m_Version = CvSplit(0)
        'm_Major = CvSplit(1)
        m_Minor = CvSplit(2)
        m_Patch = CvSplit(3)
        
        m_CodeVer = m_Version & SEP & MinusMajor & SEP & m_Minor & SEP & m_Patch
        
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        MobjUserForm.txt_VersionControlString = m_CodeVer
        Application.EnableEvents = True
            
    End Function

    Public Function MinusMinor(Minor As Long) As String

        MsCodeVer = "3.0.4.1"

        Dim CvSplit As Variant
        
        CvSplit = Split(MobjUserForm.txt_VersionControlString.Value, ".")
        
        If MobjUserForm.chk_ShowLeadingZeros.Value = True Then
            MinusMinor = Format(CLng(CvSplit(2)) - Minor, "0000")
            If MinusMinor < 0 Then MinusMinor = "0000"
        Else
            MinusMinor = Format(CLng(CvSplit(2)) - Minor, "0")
            If MinusMinor < 0 Then MinusMinor = "0"
        End If
        
        m_Version = CvSplit(0)
        m_Major = CvSplit(1)
        'm_Minor = CvSplit(2)
        m_Patch = CvSplit(3)
        
        m_CodeVer = m_Version & SEP & m_Major & SEP & MinusMinor & SEP & m_Patch
        
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        MobjUserForm.txt_VersionControlString = m_CodeVer
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        
    End Function

    Public Function MinusPatch(Patch As Long) As String

        MsCodeVer = "3.0.4.1"

        Dim CvSplit As Variant
        
        CvSplit = Split(MobjUserForm.txt_VersionControlString.Value, ".")
        
        If MobjUserForm.chk_ShowLeadingZeros.Value = True Then
            MinusPatch = Format(CLng(CvSplit(3)) - Patch, "0000")
            If MinusPatch < 0 Then MinusPatch = "0000"
        Else
            MinusPatch = Format(CLng(CvSplit(3)) - Patch, "0")
            If MinusPatch < 0 Then MinusPatch = "0"
        End If
        
        m_Version = CvSplit(0)
        m_Major = CvSplit(1)
        m_Minor = CvSplit(2)
        'm_Patch = CvSplit(3)
        
        m_CodeVer = m_Version & SEP & m_Major & SEP & m_Minor & SEP & MinusPatch
        
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        MobjUserForm.txt_VersionControlString = m_CodeVer
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        
    End Function

    Public Function MinusVersion(Version As Long) As String

        MsCodeVer = "3.0.4.1"

        Dim CvSplit As Variant
        
        CvSplit = Split(MobjUserForm.txt_VersionControlString.Value, ".")
        
        MinusVersion = Format(CLng(CvSplit(0)) - Version, "0")
        
    '    MinusVersion = Format(CLng(MobjUserForm.Version.Caption) - Version, "0")
        
        If MinusVersion < 0 Then MinusVersion = "0"
        
        If MobjUserForm.chk_UpdateVersion.Value = True Then
            Call AddCodeVerVersionConst(MobjUserForm.cbo_Workbook.Value, MinusVersion)
            MobjUserForm.chk_UpdateVersion.Value = False
        End If

        'm_Version = CvSplit(0)
        m_Major = CvSplit(1)
        m_Minor = CvSplit(2)
        m_Patch = CvSplit(3)
        
        m_CodeVer = MinusVersion & SEP & m_Major & SEP & m_Minor & SEP & m_Patch
        
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        MobjUserForm.txt_VersionControlString = m_CodeVer
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        
    End Function

    Public Function ReadCodeVer(ByVal Workbook As String, ByVal Module As String, ByVal Procedure As String) As String

        MsCodeVer = "3.0.4.1"

        Dim CodeMod  As VBIDE.CodeModule
        Dim StartLine As Long
        Dim EndLine As Long
        Dim CountOfLine As Long
        Dim TrimLines As Variant
        Dim CvSplit As String
        
        Set CodeMod = Workbooks(Workbook).VBProject.VBComponents(Module).CodeModule
        
        With CodeMod
            StartLine = GetProcInfo(Workbook, Module, Procedure, "StartLine")
            EndLine = GetProcInfo(Workbook, Module, Procedure, "EndLine")
            For CountOfLine = StartLine + 1 To EndLine - 1
                TrimLines = Trim(.Lines(CountOfLine, 1))
                If TrimLines Like "MsCodeVer = *" Then
                    CvSplit = Split(Trim(.Lines(CountOfLine, 1)), "MsCodeVer = ")(1)
                    ReadCodeVer = Mid(CvSplit, 2, Len(CvSplit) - 2)
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Next CountOfLine
            ReadCodeVer = SNOVC
        End With

    End Function

    Public Sub ReadModuleCodeVer(ByVal Workbook As String, ByVal Module As String, Optional RemoveCodeVerMod As Boolean = False)

        MsCodeVer = "3.0.4.1"

        Dim Counter As Long
        Dim CodeMod As CodeModule
        Dim TrimLines As String
        Dim CodeVerMod As String
        Dim CodeVer As CCodeVer
        Dim CvSplit As Variant
        Dim OptionExplicit As Long
        
        If Workbook = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
        If Module = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
        
        Set CodeMod = Workbooks(Workbook).VBProject.VBComponents(Module).CodeModule
        Set CodeVer = New CCodeVer
        
        'search first for const string, if found read codever
        With CodeMod
            CvSplit = Split(MobjUserForm.txt_VersionControlString.Value, ".")
            If .CountOfDeclarationLines = 0 Then
                .InsertLines 1, "Option Explicit"
                .InsertLines 2, "Private Const MSCODEVERMOD As String = " & Chr(34) & CvSplit(0) & SEP & CvSplit(1) & SEP & CvSplit(2) & Chr(34)
                Exit Sub
            ElseIf .CountOfDeclarationLines = 1 Then 'do i need to check for Option Explicit, possibly
                .InsertLines 2, "Private Const MSCODEVERMOD As String = " & Chr(34) & CvSplit(0) & SEP & CvSplit(1) & SEP & CvSplit(2) & Chr(34)
                Exit Sub
            End If
            For Counter = 1 To .CountOfDeclarationLines
                TrimLines = Trim(.Lines(Counter, 1))
                If TrimLines = "Option Explicit" Then OptionExplicit = Counter + 1
                If TrimLines Like "Private Const MSCODEVERMOD As String*" Then
                    CodeVerMod = CvSplit(0) & SEP & CvSplit(1) & SEP & CvSplit(2)
                    If RemoveCodeVerMod = True Then
                        .DeleteLines Counter, 1
                    Else
                        .ReplaceLine Counter, "Private Const MSCODEVERMOD As String = " & Chr(34) & CvSplit(0) & SEP & CvSplit(1) & SEP & CvSplit(2)
                    End If
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next Counter
            Call .InsertLines(OptionExplicit, "Private Const MSCODEVERMOD As String = " & Chr(34) & CvSplit(0) & SEP & CvSplit(1) & SEP & CvSplit(2) & Chr(34))
        End With
        
    End Sub

    Public Sub RemoveCodeVer(ByVal Workbook As String, ByVal Module As String, ByVal Procedure As String)

        MsCodeVer = "3.0.4.1"

        Dim CodeMod  As VBIDE.CodeModule
        Dim StartLine As Long
        Dim EndLine As Long
        Dim CounterOfLine As Long
        Dim TrimLines As String
        
        Set CodeMod = Workbooks(Workbook).VBProject.VBComponents(Module).CodeModule
        
        With CodeMod
            StartLine = FindLastParenthesis(Workbook, Module, Procedure)
            EndLine = GetProcInfo(Workbook, Module, Procedure, "EndLine")
            For CounterOfLine = EndLine - 1 To StartLine + 1 Step -1
                TrimLines = Trim(.Lines(CounterOfLine, 1))
                If TrimLines Like "*MsCodeVer = *" Then
                    If .Lines(CounterOfLine + 1, 1) = vbNullString Then .DeleteLines CounterOfLine + 1, 1
                    .DeleteLines CounterOfLine, 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next CounterOfLine
        End With

    End Sub

    Sub SearchModule(Workbook As String, Module As String, Procedure As String, ByVal CodeVerString As String, ByRef CodeMod As CodeModule, ByVal StartLine As Long, ByVal EndLine As Long)

        Dim CountOfLine As Long

        With CodeMod
            For CountOfLine = StartLine + 1 To EndLine - 1
                If Trim(.Lines(CountOfLine, 1)) Like "MsCodeVer = *" Then
                    .ReplaceLine CountOfLine, "    MsCodeVer = " & Chr(34) & CodeVerString & Chr(34)
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next CountOfLine
            CountOfLine = StartLine + 1
            If Not Trim(.Lines(CountOfLine, 1)) = vbNullString Then .InsertLines CountOfLine, ""
            .InsertLines CountOfLine + 1, "    MsCodeVer = " & Chr(34) & CodeVerString & Chr(34)
            If Not Trim(.Lines(CountOfLine + 2, 1)) = vbNullString Then .InsertLines CountOfLine + 2, ""
        End With
            
    End Sub
```

tried to post the entire userform but it bailed on me. so here is a few subprocs from the userform

```
    With CodeVer
    Call .AddCodeVer(objWb.Name, VbComp.Name, sProcName, MobjUserForm.txt_VersionControlString.Value)
    Call .ReadModuleCodeVer(objWb.Name, VbComp.Name)
    If Me.chk_UpdateVersion.Value = True Then
    Call .AddCodeVerVersionConst(Me.cbo_Workbook.Value, Left(.CodeVerS, 1))
    Me.chk_UpdateVersion.Value = False
    End If
    End With

    Private Sub AddMajor_Click()

        MsCodeVer = "3.0.4.1"

        Dim CodeVer As CCodeVer
        Set CodeVer = New CCodeVer
        
        With CodeVer
            If Me.chk_ShowLeadingZeros.Value = True Then
                .CodeVerS = CStr(Format(.AddMajor(1), "0000"))
            Else
                .CodeVerS = CStr(Format(.AddMajor(1), "0"))
            End If
        End With

    End Sub
```

and here is the code to launch my userform in the VBE

```
    Public Sub A0Show_Dim()

        MsCodeVer = "3.0.4.1"

        'this binds the userform to the VBE, and since it is modeless, you can edit the userform
        'code as needed
        On Error GoTo errHandler
        
        Dim MobjUserform As UDim
        Dim lAppHwnd As Long
        Dim lMeHwnd As Long
        Dim lRes   As Long
        Dim objVbp As VBProject
        
        Const SUFCLASS As String = "ThunderDFrame"

        Set objVbp = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject
        Set MobjUserform = New UDim
        Load MobjUserform
        
        lAppHwnd = Application.VBE.MainWindow.hwnd

        If lAppHwnd > 0 Then
            lMeHwnd = FindWindow(SUFCLASS, MobjUserform.Caption)
            lRes = SetParent(lMeHwnd, lAppHwnd)
            If lRes = 0 Then
                MsgBox "The call to Set Parent failed."
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Unable to get the window handle of the Excel Application."
        End If
        
        With MobjUserform
            .cbo_SelectWorkbook.BackColor = MCOMBOBOXBACKCOLOR
            .cbo_ContainerName.BackColor = MCOMBOBOXBACKCOLOR
            .cbo_ProcedureName.BackColor = MCOMBOBOXBACKCOLOR
            Set .Vbp = objVbp
            .Show vbModeless
        End With
        
        Exit Sub
        
    errHandler:
                
        Debug.Print Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
        Stop
        Resume
        
    End Sub
```

working on posting the whole workbook.

Comment: Can you give an overall description of what this class should do in relation to your other objects, code, workbooks, and VBA modules (since it looks like it operates on VBA code itself)?

Comment: Why are you hardcoding `MsCodeVer = "3.0.4.1"` in multiple places?

Comment: Peter, the class assigns various strings to the build number. so the build might look like '3.4.5.1' which would be the version.major.minor.patch. when picking set codever button, it assigns (or replaces) the current 'MsCodeVer' with the new string. so basically, I have a global var MsCodeVer that is used in every procedure in the workbook (if so desired) to help in tracking when i update a proc or module. I have other addins that use these global vars that can update libraries automatically. So, for me, this is helpful in tracking the development of code

Comment: HackSlash, see comment above for clarification. really wish I could just publish the workbook and then you would see it all working together.

Comment: I can't help thinking semantic version numbers have nothing - and I mean _nothing whatsoever_ - nothing to do in source code, even less at such a granular level. A version number for a variable? For a constant? Something is off. Change logs belong in source control, and version numbers belong in git tags/releases, not in source code... I see you're using Rubberduck - have you tried synchronizing the project with a folder, and adding that folder to source control, like a git repository? It's pretty much the industry standard solution for the kind of tracking you're looking for!

Comment: Thanks, Mattieu for that comment, I think rather than say my app is not right to do what I want, it's more of 'did i get the class right?' and not 'this app has no use'. since this is my first class, my question is relating to class structure and did I implement it correctly? as for synchronizing the project, will look into that. thanks for rubberduck, glad that it is working for me.

Comment: @DanM that is fair enough, your concept can be reviewed in isolation from a style & architecture p.o.v. It looks like this class has some methods to loop through open workbooks and all the procedures in them, adding and deleting these code version assignment lines. I would really like to see the code which calls this one, as well as maybe some of the code in other addins that leverage these version numbers. I don't understand why they are not constants, why every procedure must assign them etc. This is relevant context to review as it would inform any suggestions on possible improvements

Comment: You can upload a workbook on Dropbox, I use GitHub to share files. However many people won't want to open random files on the internet, so you should put all the necessary content in the question to make sure it is standalone, and has all the context you want reviewers to see. Also links die.

Comment: Greedo, thanks for the input. will post the Userform code where all the action happens. I can either use dropbox or onedrive for the link, but i agree with you that links die. let me update the original post with updated vba code.

Comment: @Greedo, here is the link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/e08gxifshthda51/CodeVerClass.xlam?dl=0

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to be rude or anything, it's just that it had to be said (it's not uncommon for VBA devs to not even know about source control, since the VBIDE has nothing to integrate with it) - feedback on the code I'll post as an answer, not as a comment ;-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, you weren't being rude. And I am a dev that doesn't know much about source control. I looked at various apps but didn't fully understand how to make them work, so I set out to do sc inside excel. just an exercise for me to see if I could make it work. Since I have other apps that use my sc, it is working for me. But will educate myself on how to use git if that is the right app to use. and thanks in advance for posting an answer on my code. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Greedo, just reread your comment and I guess the var could be a constant, wouldn't take too much effort to recode that. from a programming standpoint, is a constant (in this case) better than a public? can you explain why so I get a full understanding? thanks again for your comments.

Comment: @DanM that depends on how these strings are used. You've included the code to create/update them, but it's unclear how a function would use these global variables? At runtime? You said you have more addins that manipulate/use the version strings, what do they do with them? If they are never used at runtime they might as well be comments rather than variables. You see the more context the better for making suggestions. Ps your second code block looks broken (very indented)

Comment: @Greedo, do you want me to add a link to UpdateLibrary.xlam? this demonstrates how to use the var's to update modules. that would be the fastest way to 'see' how it uses these vars. lmk. and i fixed the broken block (the portion that was way over indented).

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: If you have an improved version of your code you'd like reviewed, please post a new question instead. Feel free to add a link in the new question pointing back to this one for additional context, the questions will appear as linked in the sidebar when you do that.

Answer (score 1):

One of the first observations is that the `CCodeVer` internally calls out to external code modules (`MobjUserForm` and at least one other `StandardModule`).  `ClassModules` ('Classes' going forward) should be completely 'self-contained' - meaning once created and initialized, all dependencies are satisfied internally.  And, any additional run-time dependencies are provided as arguments of its `Public` functions.

Software is a typically architected as a set of layers (e.g., UI, Domain, Data).  And, typically, the implementation strives to keep Domain layer objects like `CCodeVer` completely unaware and independent of UI modules.  The current implementation of `CCodeVer` both knows about `MobjUserForm` and assumes that it can always *call back* to `MobjUserForm's` controls properties.

So, the `CCodeVer` class *depends* on the co-existence of the external objects in order to fulfill its responsibilities.  Take, for instance all the references to `MobjUserForm` control values.  What if you would want to write an automated test for some of the functions exposed by `CCodeVer`?  Your test setup would need a `MobjUserForm` instance - otherwise `CCodeVer` will not *compile*.

**Code content:**

From the book "Clean Code" (Robert C. Martin)

> The first rule of functions is that they should be small.  The second
> rule of functions is that *they should be smaller than that*.

That's nice, but the question asked is about using `ClassModules` in VBA - not functions.  In the same book, there is, of course, a chapter about classes.  The chapter on classes contains the following:

> The first rule of classes is that they should be small.  The second
> rule of classes is that *they should be smaller than that*.

So yeah, keeping *everything* small is stressed as a really good idea.  Small functions are evaluated simply in terms of lines of code.  Small *classes* are evaluated in terms of `Public` subroutines and functions - which in combination, describe the responsibilities of a class.

**A Few Principles:**

Achieving the above goals for both functions and classes depend primarily on two principles.  The first is the "Don't Repeat Yourself" ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) principle and the second is the Single Responsibility Principle ([SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)).  There are certainly other useful principles in software design.  But, with regard to making code elements *smaller*, DRY and SRP probably represent the *20* part of the 80/20 rule (the Pareto Principle... *this is the last principle mentioned in this answer, I promise*).  That is, of all code design principles (IMO), applying DRY and SRP, lead to 80% of function and class size reductions.

Function `AddCodeVer` is around 172 lines long.  By any standard, that is *a lot* of code for one function.  However, it can be made smaller by applying the DRY principle.  DRY would have you remove the following repeated block of code:

```
Set VbProj = Wb.VBProject
For Each VbComp In VbProj.VBComponents
    Module = VbComp.Name
    Set CodeMod = VbComp.CodeModule
    With CodeMod
        LineNum = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1
        Do Until LineNum >= .CountOfLines
            Procedure = .ProcOfLine(LineNum, ProcKind)
            Select Case ProcKind
                Case vbext_pk_Get
                    Procedure = Procedure & "  (Get)"
                Case vbext_pk_Let
                    Procedure = Procedure & "  (Let)"
                Case vbext_pk_Set
                    Procedure = Procedure & "  (Set)"
            End Select
            If ProcKind = vbext_pk_Proc Then
                StartLine = .ProcBodyLine(Procedure, vbext_pk_Proc)
                EndLine = StartLine - 2 + .ProcCountLines(Procedure, vbext_pk_Proc)
                Call SearchModule(Workbook, Module, Procedure, CodeVerString, CodeMod, StartLine, EndLine)
            End If
            LineNum = .ProcStartLine(Split(Procedure, "  (")(0), ProcKind) + _
                .ProcCountLines(Split(Procedure, "  (")(0), ProcKind) + 1
        Loop
    End With
Next VbComp
```

The above codeblock is 27 lines that are repeated *verbatim* 3 times in `AddCodeVer`. Moving these lines into a dedicated function results in 27 x 3 = 81 lines removed from `AddCodeVer`.  That's 54 net fewer lines to maintain and there are other similar opportunities.

With regard to classes, the `CCodeVer` class exposes 24 `Public` methods and properties.  Do the 24 `Public` methods represent a single responsibility?  `CCodeVer` appears to have at least 2 high-level responsibilities:

1. Add version content to modules
2. Support increments to the version.

One possible simplification is to have `CCodeVer` contain a new class `CodeVersion` (change the name to fit your needs).  `CodeVersion` handles responsibility #2 above (the code below is only a partial implementation):

```
'Class CodeVersion
Option Explicit

Private m_Fields() As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim mFields(4)
    mFields(0) = "3" 'Version
    mFields(1) = "0" 'Major
    mFields(2) = "4" 'Minor
    mFields(3) = "1" 'Patch
    
End Sub

Public Sub SetCodeVersion(ByVal cVersion As String)
    mFields = Split(cVersion, ".")
End Sub

Public Function AsString() As String
    AsString = Join(mFields, ".")
End Function

Public Function AddMajor(ByVal Major As Long, ByVal showLeadingZeroes As Boolean) As String
    
    AddMajor = SetValue(mFields(1), Major, showLeadingZeroes)
    
    If AddMajor > 9999 Then
        AddMajor = "0"
        mFields(1) = "0"
        mFields(0) = CStr(CLng(mFields(0) + 1))
    End If
    If CLng(mFields(0)) >= 999999 Then
        MsgBox ("Resetting to base string")
        mFields(0) = "0"
        mFields(1) = "0"
        mFields(2) = "0"
        mFields(3) = "0"
    End If
    
    AddMajor = Me.AsString()
    
End Function

Public Function AddMinor(ByVal Minor As Long, ByVal showLeadingZeroes As Boolean) As String

    AddMinor = SetValue(mFields(2), Minor, showLeadingZeroes)
    
    If AddMinor > 9999 Then
        AddMinor = "0"
        mFields(2) = "0"
        mFields(1) = CStr(CLng(mFields(1) + 1))
    End If
    If CLng(mFields(1)) > 9999 Then
        mFields(1) = "0"
        mFields(0) = CStr(CLng(mFields(0) + 1))
    End If
    If CLng(mFields(0)) >= 999999 Then
        mFields(0) = "0"
        If mFields(1) = "9999" Then mFields(1) = "0"
        If mFields(2) = "9999" Then mFields(2) = "0"
        If mFields(3) = "9999" Then mFields(3) = "0"
    End If
    
    AddMinor = Me.AsString()
    
End Function

Private Function SetValue(ByRef inputVal As String, ByVal elementIncrement As Long, ByVal showLeadingZeros As Boolean) As String
    If showLeadingZeros = True Then
        SetValue = Format(CLng(inputVal) + elementIncrement, "0000")
    Else
        SetValue = Format(CLng(inputVal) + elementIncrement, "0")
    End If
End Function
```

This would result in `CCodeVer` looking something like:

```
Option Explicit

'{...... code ...........}

Public Function AddMajor(Major As Long) As String
     
    Dim cVersion As CodeVersion
    Set cVersion = New CodeVersion
    cVersion.SetCodeVersion MobjUserForm.txt_VersionControlString.Value
    
    m_CodeVer = cVersion.AddMajor(Major, MobjUserForm.chk_ShowLeadingZeros.Value)

    MobjUserForm.txt_VersionControlString = m_CodeVer
        
    ResetFlags
    
    AddMajor = m_CodeVer
End Function

Public Function AddMinor(Minor As Long) As String

    Dim cVersion As CodeVersion
    Set cVersion = New CodeVersion
    cVersion.SetCodeVersion MobjUserForm.txt_VersionControlString.Value

    m_CodeVer = cVersion.AddMinor(Minor, MobjUserForm.chk_ShowLeadingZeros.Value)
    
    MobjUserForm.txt_VersionControlString = m_CodeVer
    
    ResetFlags
    
    AddMinor = mCodeVer
        
End Function

Private Sub ResetFlags()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

'{...... code ...........}
```

The primary improvement is that `CodeVersion` has zero dependencies on any global variables or the `UserForm`.  It is now possible to write test code that exercises code like `CodeVersion.AddMinor` with various inputs.  No other modules are required for `CodeVersion` to fulfill its responsibilities.

Further, `CCodeVer` no longer contains the code responsible for incrementing version strings.  It is now *smaller* because it has delegated that work to a more specialized object.  `CCodeVer's` `Public` interface now has the option to expose a single `Get` property for a `CodeVersion` object and remove all the `Let/Get` properties (depending on how these properties are actually used).

`CCodeVer` retains the responsibility of writing version strings to the various workbooks.  But, even that responsibility can be, and perhaps should be, implemented by yet another class.  Doing so would result in `CCodeVer` having the single responsibility of a coordinating interactions between the UI layer and the appropriate Domain layer objects.

One way in that `ClassModule` programing differs from `StandardModule` programming is that classes can be built-up using other classes.  Classes can contain classes...whereas `StandardModules` cannot *contain* other `StandardModules` but rather have to interact through globally available functions and variables.  Additionally, `StandardModules` cannot be passed into functions as arguments or exposed as a function return value...but classes can.

It's great that you are adding `ClassModules` to your set of VBA tools.  By adding classes to your VBA code, you are embarking on a path towards Object Oriented Programming (OOP).  To move you along the OOP learning curve more quickly, you will benefit from studying the references mentioned above as well as content available [here](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/).

Comment: that is exactly the code review that i was looking for. did i get my Class right (I didn't). will have to reread and unpack what you have said but this is what I was looking for. thanks for the lengthy reply. will do as you have said, will come back here if I run into any problems.

Comment: My first question is should i move the ShowUCodeVer code to the class then? that way the code is all in the class. did I understand this correctly? (don't think so as I am running into compile issues)

Comment: But now the issues are gone, and it loads up. need further testing but I would like to post my new GET/SET property for your review. seems like I might have it. still rereading your post to get further understanding

Comment: So something is wrong with my GET. see the following two statements, what did i do wrong?  
Public Property Get MUserform() As UCodeVerClass: Set MUserform = m_Userform: End Property

Public Property Set MUserform(ByRef UF As UCodeVerClass): Set m_Userform = UF: End Property

Comment: it fails on the Get

Comment: What’s the error message?

Comment: Run time error 91 object variable or with block variable not set, it seems that the error is on the line that is trying to get the value of a combobox from the userform that is displayed. dont think i got the .Show part right. any ideas?

Comment: so I took time off from this project so that I could reflect on what I learned about classes. 
so I created 20 new classes based on my portfolio. Finally, I had enough information to properly fix the issues. And the cool thing is, it worked right the first time that I ran it. Is it helpful if I post the new classes for review?